# AS3 ScaleX is moving object across screen

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make an HP bar for my game. I have the code here

```
private var hpBar:Sprite = new Sprite();
private function drawHPBar(s:Stage):void{
    hpBar.graphics.beginFill(0xFF1717); //Medium Red
    hpBar.graphics.drawRect(620, 165, 152, 22);
    hpBar.graphics.endFill();
    s.addChild(hpBar);
    s.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, displayKey);
}

private function displayKey(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    hpBar.scaleX -= 0.02;
}`
```

But when the hpBar.scaleX is decreased, the object shrinks and at the same time, moves left across the screen(stage). I am so confused because I saw videos on youtube about the scaleX and they don't seem to have a problem.

Comment: Maybe because the scale is applying from the top-left corner and not from the middle

Comment: I don't think its that. Can someone help please I have been having trouble with this for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Finally!!

I had to set the X and Y manually, and leave the X and Y blank when I created a rectangle.

Here's an example:

```
        hpBar.x = 620;
        hpBar.y = 165;
        hpBar.graphics.beginFill(0xFF1717); //Medium Red
        hpBar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 152, 22);
```

Now, when the scaleX is changed, it will no longer move across the screen.